# Sharing value between two recyclerviews in one activity for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview

How to share value between two RecyclerView? That are in one Activity? Below is my code with just one RecyclerView binding. That is OK and I understand how it works. What I want to add another RecyclerView in the same page. Both RecyclerViews are tables. When user clicked on item in first RecyclerView anything changed in second RecyclerView. Repository usually returns List of data from Room database.
What I appreciate would be some code example or maybe some tutorial with example.

This is MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val oneViewModel: OneViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMaindBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val recyclerViewOneAdapter = RecyclerViewOneAdapter ()
        binding.apply {
            recyclerViewOneAdapter.apply {
                adapter = Adapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            }
            oneViewModel.getItems.observe(this@MainActivity){
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

This is ViewModel example

```
@HiltViewModel
class OneViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: SybaseRepository
): ViewModel(){
    val getItems = repository.getAllItemsFromDatabase().asLiveData()    
}
```

What I suggest is something like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val oneViewModel: OneViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMaindBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        val recyclerViewOneAdapter = RecyclerViewOneAdapter ()
        val recyclerViewSecondAdapter = RecyclerViewSecondAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            recyclerViewOneAdapter.apply {
                adapter = recyclerViewOneAdapter 
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            }
            oneViewModel.getFirstItems.observe(this@MainActivity){
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
                recyclerViewTwoAdapter.apply {
                adapter = recyclerViewSecondAdapter 
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            }
            oneViewModel.getSecondItems.observe(this@MainActivity){
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

This is ViewModel example

```
@HiltViewModel
class OneViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: SybaseRepository
): ViewModel(){
    val getFirstItems = repository.getFirsttemsFromDatabase().asLiveData()  
    val getSecondItems = repository.getSecondItemsFromDatabase().asLiveData()    
}
```

Am I missing something? Or is it correct way?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @Praveen at this moment just fill two recyclerviews in one activity with viewmodel.

Comment: Is your code not doing that or is it showing some error?